# gcloud init cli command :ERROR: gcloud crashed (ValueError): the query contains a null character

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

I am trying to initialize my gcloud settings for a project. But when I run the gcloud init command, it gives error gcloud crashed.

It was previously working but all of sudden today this command crashed. I tried 'gcloud auth login' and pasted the credentials, but it still gives the same error

```
    gcloud init
    Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

    Settings from your current configuration [default] are:
    core:
    disable_usage_reporting: 'False'

    Pick configuration to use:
    [1] Re-initialize this configuration [default] with new settings
    [2] Create a new configuration
    Please enter your numeric choice:  1

    Your current configuration has been set to: [default]

    You can skip diagnostics next time by using the following flag:
    gcloud init --skip-diagnostics

    Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
    Checking network connection...done.
    Reachability Check passed.
    Network diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).

    ERROR: gcloud crashed (ValueError): the query contains a null character

    If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
    gcloud feedback

    To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
    gcloud info --run-diagnostics

The actual results should be like below: 
    gcloud init

    Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

    Settings from your current configuration [default] are:
    core:
    account: prajakta@gmail.com
    disable_usage_reporting: 'False'
    project: default-1234

    Pick configuration to use:
    [1] Re-initialize this configuration [default] with new settings
    [2] Create a new configuration
    Please enter your numeric choice:  1

    Your current configuration has been set to: [default]

    You can skip diagnostics next time by using the following flag:
    gcloud init --skip-diagnostics

    Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
    Checking network connection...done.
    Reachability Check passed.
    Network diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).

   Choose the account you would like to use to perform operations for
   this configuration:
   [1] prajakta@gmail.com
   [2] Log in with a new account
   Please enter your numeric choice:  1

   Pick cloud project to use:
   [1] default-1234
   [2] abc-project
   [3] Create a new project
   Please enter numeric choice or text value (must exactly match list
   item):  1

   Your current project has been set to: [default-1234].

   Your Google Cloud SDK is configured and ready to use!
```

Comment: did u resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

From the output that you included, it appears to have completed successfully:

```
Your Google Cloud SDK is configured and ready to use!
```

Are you able to use any commands?

```
gcloud config list
gcloud auth list
gcloud projects list
```

It's not clear which operating system you're using *but* it's probable that either some dependent piece of software was upgraded and caused the break; and|or Cloud SDK (aka `gcloud`) has upgraded on your machine and it is broken.

You may be best-placed to contact Google Cloud Support, or if you don't have a support contract, to file an issue on Google issue tracker for gcloud here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143

**NB** You've included your email address and several of your projects in your question, you may wish to redact these as they're not necessary to help answer the question.